# CRISPR-Cas Systems

Tags: dna, microbiology, crispr

In the context of the bacterial systems (not the gene editing tool), I was wondering what happens to the foreign DNA after the Cas proteins have created a new spacer.

It is really not clear to me, most of the documentation I have found focuses on the subsequent steps (expression and interference) and do not discuss the fate of said foreign DNA. For example, see this image from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRISPR#/media/File:Crispr.png

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you mean.  Do you mean what happens to the foreign DNA or what happens to the spacer?  The former is cleaved to form a spacer, the latter is inserted into the genome.

Comment: Ok thanks, how do you know that it is cleaved? Are there endonuclease activities in the proteins that deal with the foreign DNA? I was under the impression that the spacer was created by copy of the protospacer of interest.

Comment: @AlterSid Cas is that endonuclease. Please read about CRISPR-Cas and ask specific questions if you have any. Wikipedia is good enough.

Comment: Try this paper http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20056882 it makes a nice overview of the all process and if you want to go deeper check the references, they cover all the passages involved in the CRISPR mediated immunity.

Comment: Do CRISPR systems attack the entire DNA of the virus or certain specific DNAs (dictated by the spacers)?